Samsung refrigerator light
This is a question about “Jewish law or practice (what to do or why),” in particular, Shabbat observance.
The Samsung refridgerator model RF18A5101SR can turn off lights for Shabbat by placing magnets above its French doors. Is it also possible to turn off the lights for Shabbat in its lower freezer drawer? Thank you.

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. This question does not seem to fall within the scope of this website. Please see the help center for more info. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help

I do not think it is possible. I've been avoiding using the freezer on Shabbos in my Samsung fridge.  You may want to contact the company to investigate.

You could remove the lightbulb and this won't be an issue anymore

@Dude Unfortunately that's likely not the case. The light is but a symptom of the computer in the fridge turning on when it notices the door open. It could also turn off the fan, adjust the cooling schedule, etc. You need to trick it to think the door is still closed. Unscrewing the lightbulb only works in old "dumb" fridges.

Here's a possible video to "unskrew" the bulb, but it may trigger other actions inside the fridge. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEBcnMFC7r8
